# The mailSettings attributes are all returning <Null>

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, configurationmanager

### Problem

When grabbing the `_mailSettings.Smtp.Network.Host`, even though it's in the application configuration file, it's returning `null`.

---

### Code

First and foremost, because the project is just a `Class Library`, I have the following post-build event to build the properly named configuration file:

```
copy "$(ProjectDir)App.config" "$(TargetDir)ApplicationSupport.Email.dll.config"
```

next I have a class that is intended to load the configuration and make it available:

```
public class Startup
{
    SmtpSection _smtpSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.net/mailSettings/smtp") as SmtpSection;

    public string SmtpServer
    {
        get
        {
            if (_smtpSection == null) { return string.Empty; }
            return _smtpSection.Network.Host;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

and I'm trying to unit test it:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestStartupSettings()
{
    var sut = new ApplicationSupport.Email.Startup();
    Assert.AreEqual("test.mail.com", sut.SmtpServer);
}
```

and I ***thought*** I should be getting data since I've got this configured in the application configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="somebody@test.com">
        <network host="test.mail.com" defaultCredentials="true" port="25"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You never parse the `SectionGroup` or set `SmtpServer` to any value before you asset the value.  You load the configuration but you don't set it equal to the value your expecting.  Furthermore why do you return a empty string instead of trying to load the value?

Comment: @Ramhound, shouldn't it be reading it from the application configuration file?

Comment: It doesn't do so automatically.  You never tell it what value contained in the configuration file to use.  I don't believe `_mailSettings.Smtp.Network.Host` be that.  Its entirely possible part of the problem is that `network host` has space contained within it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are some issues surrounding using the `ConfigurationManager` in a `Class Library`, I chose to simply use the `Settings` tab in the `Project Properties` because that generates an `app.config` file with data that I can simply copy and paste into the `web.config` of the running application for example.

It also allows me to easily unit test the application.